# Vlookup computer names and find latest date from date column on multiple sheets

Tags: vba, vlookup

I'm a total newb when it comes to vlookup, and it's quite confusing to me.  I've tried the examples on Stack overflow but I'm just not able to get it to work.  I started to write some VBA, but I think Vlookup would be WAY easier if I can figure it out.

I have a Excel sheet that has 3 different sheets, Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3.  For simplicity's sake, they all have the same structure.  They contain one column for computer name, and one for date.  The computer names should exist as matches across all sheets, but they may not.  See below for example.

Sheet 1:

```
Computer Name          Date    
Computer B             1/9/2019    
Computer F             4/3/2019    
Computer D             2/22/2019
```

Sheet 2:

```
Computer Name          Date    
Computer D             10/27/2015    
Computer C             2/6/2019    
Computer B             5/3/2019
```

Sheet 3:

```
Computer Name          Date    
Computer F             1/28/2019    
Computer C             10/12/2018    
Computer Q             9/29/2017
```

What I want to end up with is a 4th sheet (Sheet4) that contains a row for each computer name found, and the latest date found associated with that computer name.  So for example:

Sheet 4:

```
Computer Name          Latest Date    
Computer B             5/3/2019    
Computer D             2/22/2019    
Computer Q             9/29/2017
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this something that is a one time need or an on going need.  One time, just copy paste the data onto one sheet and use a pivot table.  On going, vba will be the best.  Cycle the sheets and use a dictionary to get the unique names as the key and replace the value(date) if the new data is later.

Comment: Yea this is an ongoing need.  We'll prob do this once per month.  I'm not sure what you mean by use a dictionary to get the unique names as the key and replace the date?